# Achieving Eclipse-like OSGi launcher

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

I am building an OSGi application and need to create an Eclipse-like OSGi application launcher.

For those who do not know, when an OSGi application is run through Eclipse's OSGi framework, Equinox launches and automatically manages the order of bundles being started and stopped. From what I have experienced so far, it seems to be very efficient in what it does.

I want a similar piece of software to be able to create powerful distributable OSGi applications that can take a dynamic group of bundles, and without rewriting any code, start the application correctly and in the right bundle order.

I am curious to know how Eclipse achieves this result efficiently and how I can achieve the same result.

Thank you,

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:
1) use [pax runner](http://paxrunner.ops4j.org/space/Pax+Runner)
2) Use eclipse bundle witch serves as starter ( i believe it's `org.eclipse.equinox.launcher`)

**Edit:**
1*)For equinox options starter see [this link](http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/documents/quickstart.php) paragraph *Configurations and all that...* BTW I've been wrong it's not launcher bundle it's common and update bundles.
2*)Fox pax runner example see [this screen cast](http://paxrunner.ops4j.org/display/paxrunner/Pax+Runner+-+Screencast+-+Using+Directory+Scanner)

Comment: Can you please shortly describe how the automatic bundle ordering works in both of these options?

Comment: Yes, a short description of how this works would be very helpful.